# Using hammer.js on dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, hammer.js

I'm playing around with hammer.js for a web app.

I can get it to work just fine, except on content loaded with ajax.

I use the hammer.js special-events plugin for jquery.

The following works fine:

```
$('#menu a').on("tap", function(event) {
 //console.log(event);
});
```

But when I use the jquery delegation syntax:

```
$('body').on("tap", '#menu a', function(event) {
 //console.log(event);
});
```

Nothing happens...

What is the right syntax?

Comment: Has there been any insight as to which method works for dynamically loaded content?

Comment: I can't recall getting it to work. So I turned to jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 4):

Try this if you dynamically add the `a` element :

```
$('#menu').on("tap", 'a', function(event) {
  //console.log(event);
});
```

or this:

```
$('#menu').hammer().on("tap", 'a', function(event) {
  //console.log(event);
});
```