# HammerJS on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am trying to add HammerJS: http://hammerjs.github.io/api/

for dynamically added element.

```
 Hammer.on('.vc', "tap", function (ev) {
                console.log(ev.type);
            });
```

Doesn't work however. I get this error:

```
TypeError: target.addEventListener is not a function. (In 'target.addEventListener(type, handler, false)', 'target.addEventListener' is undefined)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `parent-selector` with `.hammer` and use `.on` handler over `hammer-wrapped` object.

```js
$('PARENT_ELEMENT_SELECTOR').hammer().on("tap", ".vc", function() {
  alert("tapped!!");
});
```

Comment: Did you test this? hammer() function no more works. It says undefined. I know the code is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267364/using-hammer-js-on-dynamically-loaded-content but it is for old version I would think.

Comment: Refer sample code provided over `jQuery-plugin` in hammer docs, `$(element).hammer(options).bind("pan", myPanHandler);`

Comment: Amazing! Thanks dear! You made my day. This is what I was missing.

Comment: @TimLiberty, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_